# How to draw on a canvas using x, y coords that are relative to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a game where you shoot at objects. I am stuck however with determining where the user is clicking. I have a canvas and a circle in the middle. The goal is to draw a circle where ever I click on the canvas, however the circle gets drawn slightly off from the cursor. The distance between the circle and the cursor depends on how close is the cursor from the top-left corner of the canvas, where the farther the click is from the top-left corner, the farther the distance is between where the circle is drawn and where I actually clicked.

This is how the website looks like, and how far the circle is drawn, since I can't show the cursor in screenshots, I have clicked on the center of the white circle, and this is where it drew the red circle:
[image of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cMqW.png)

And this is the code

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const dimensions = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
canvas.width = dimensions.width * devicePixelRatio
canvas.height = dimensions.height * devicePixelRatio
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')


class Player {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fill()
  }
}

class Projectile {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color, speed) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
    this.speed = speed
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fill()
  }
}

// get the center of canvas
const x = canvas.width / 2
const y = canvas.height / 2

// make player
const player = new Player(x, y, 50, 'white')

player.draw()


// get the mouse position relative to the canvas and not the window
function getCursorPositionX(canvas, event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  const xc = event.clientX - rect.left
  return xc
}

function getCursorPositionY(canvas, event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  const yc = event.clientY - rect.top
  return yc
}

// add an event listner to detect clicks
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {

  const projectile = new Projectile(getCursorPositionX(canvas, e), getCursorPositionY(canvas, e), 10, 'red', null)
  console.log(getCursorPositionX(canvas, e), getCursorPositionX(canvas, e))
  projectile.draw()
})
```

```css
.gameWindow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: #232323;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content center">
  <h1 class="title2">Quick Shot</h1>
  <canvas class="gameWindow"></canvas>
  <script src=./index.js></script>
</div>
```

Comment: All canvas coordinates are, by definition, relative to the canvas top-left corner. So if you want to make "where the user's cursor is", you get the mouse/touch event's `offsetX`/`offsetY` coordinates and those should immediately work.

Comment: Problem is likely somewhere else in your code you didnt share, as you can see from the interactive code it works as you would expect

Comment: (and note: using `offsetX`/`offsetY` will always work, _even if you use CSS transforms_, e.g. https://jsbin.com/kijaxetewu/edit?css,js,output)

Comment: Remove width: 95% and it works fine.

Comment: @LeeLenalee It does not work in the code snippet. I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: What I mean by it is that you said that when you clicked in the white the dot was way out on the grey, when I clicked in the code snippet on the white the dot appeared where I clicked

Comment: @Justin I can't just do that, I want it to have a set width, plus doing that makes the game window much wider than the actual window.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have fixed the offset issue with your code but that required me to remove `width: 95%` so now the window is way too big (because of the top part in the js file) and I don't know how to make it fit sideways without using width.

Comment: nevermind, I got it working. Just resized it with `canvas.width = innerWidth`